# How can I find modulus and argument of $z=(1+i)^n$

Tags: complex-numbers

The complex numbers are such that : 
$z=(1+i)^n$.
Find the modulus and argument of
complex-numbers.

Comment: Begin by finding modulus and agument of $1+i$.

Comment: and after?.....

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn’t a site that will solve your homework for you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has shown no personal effort and appears to be merely asking someone to work their homework problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either by DeMoivre's formula or Euler's identity, it can be shown that for complex $z$ and integer $n$, $|z^n| = |z|^n$. So $|(1+i)^n| = |1+i|^n = \sqrt 2^n$. With the same idea, write $z$ in the trig form, prove that $\mathrm{cis} a \cdot \mathrm{cis} b = \mathrm{cis} (a+b)$ so it follows that $z^n = |z|^n \mathrm{cis} (n\theta)$. Try to find $\mathrm{arg} (1+i)$ as an exercise.

Comment: Prove that if $a, b \in \Bbb C$, then $|ab| = |a||b|$. Then use induction.

Comment: thank you and what about argument ?

Comment: Oh my, sorry. I'll complete it.

Comment: okay i wait you thank you

Comment: I HAVE other number please help me

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Write $1+i$ in [trigonometric form](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Trigonometric_Form_of_the_Complex_Number).

Comment: how ,,?.........

Comment: @user499303 Your teacher told you what the modulus is. Simply use the definition.

Comment: i know what is the modulus but i can't find this only :)

Comment: and what about ^n

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:
$$\forall z\in \mathbb{C}: z = |z|(\cos(\alpha)+i\sin(\alpha))$$ 
Where $|z| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ if $z = a + bi; a, b \in \mathbb{R}$
Then you can use this" [de Moivre formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)

Thus we get:
$$z^n = |z|^n(\cos(n\alpha)+i\sin(n\alpha))$$

Comment: z=(1+i)^n  ?,,,,

Comment: I have edited my post so you can use it to calculate $z^n$